# jquery sortable refresh => what is the correct syntax in coffeescript?

Tags: jquery, refresh, coffeescript, jquery-ui-sortable

i'm trying to apply the "refresh" trigger in my coffeescript code, but I don't find the correct syntax:

in standard jquery, it would be: $('.milestone_chain').sortable('refresh')

What would it be in coffeescript, knowing that this is my code:

```
  $('.milestone_chain').sortable
    axis: 'y'
    containment: 'parent'
    cursor: 'move'
    tolerance: 'pointer'
    update: (event,ui)->
        $('li > a > div > span.number').each (i, element)  =>
            $(element).html i+1
        $.ajax($(this).attr('data-update-url') + '/' + ui.item.attr('id') + '/reorder/' + (ui.item.index() + '.js'))
```

The html is the following:

```
   <ul class="milestone_chain" data-update-url="projectmilestones">
      <% projectcapstone.projectmilestones.rank(:rank).includes(:projectdepartment).each.with_index do |projectmilestone, i|  %>


              <li class="milestone_<%=projectmilestone.projectdepartment.ranking%>" id="<%=projectmilestone.id%>">
                <div class="chainpie"><%= percent_pie(projectmilestone.status)%></div>
                <div class="milestone<%=projectmilestone.projectdepartment.ranking%>"><%= link_to content_tag(:span, i+1, :class => "number"), projects_projectmilestone_path(projectmilestone) %></div>
                <div class="milestonenum">
                  <%= link_to projectmilestone.name, projects_projectmilestone_path(projectmilestone) %>
                  <b class="notch"></b>
                </div>
              </li>


      <% end %>
   </ul>
```

It is working well. The problem is that the code needs sometimes to be loaded in Ajax and then it doesn't work anymore. This is why I want to implement the refresh method. If I understood correctly, it addresses this issue

Thanks!

Comment: What, exactly, is your problem?  When I apply your code to the coffee compiler, I get Javascript that I would expect... everything below the `sortable` is an object with the options you specify.  What isn't working?

Comment: My problem is that it doesn't work when the html is loaded in Ajax. I updated the post to give more info about the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that Refresh wasn't supposed to be triggered in the above question but after reloading the Ajax bloc of code, as part of the ajax function loading this code.

Should be obvious for javascript pro's but not for newbies like me... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly valid CoffeeScript:

```
$('.milestone_chain').sortable('refresh')
```

as is

```
$('.milestone_chain').sortable 'refresh'
```

Comment: When I do it the first way, I get the error message "$(".milestone_chain").sortable("refresh") is not a function", when I do it the second way, nothing happens at all...  Thx!

Comment: There is something else going wrong in your code. Did you mix tabs and spaces for indentation? Where is this running?

Comment: It is running on an intranet but I posted the html code in the code above.

Answer (score -1):

Try to devide your code for more small parts for example move callback down and try to find error after that.
In coffee you don't need so long line for ajax. Try to improve your code, use string interpolations. Your code will looks like something like this:

```
$.ajax "#{$(this).attr 'data-update-url'}/#{ui.item.attr 'id'}/reorder/#{ui.item.index()}.js"
```

Comment: Actually, the callback works fine, as long as I don't load my list in Ajax. So, I don't see how moving it down could help. The problem seems to lie in the 'refresh' statement but I just receive an error message telling me that 'refresh is not a function'. I'm very new to javascript/coffeescript and I don't understand very well how this refresh statement should work. I'm confused...

Comment: Click it in firebug. And you will see what happens really in your compiled JS-code (not coffee). I think you might have problem with 'this' pointer. It may be not as you're expecting.